# rxjs interval is triggering twice

Tags: rxjs, angular7

I am trying to implement the logout functionality if the user has been active on the system for 1 hour i have to logout the user, i am using "interval" of `Rxjs` on `onInit()` method. However this is printing value twice.

I tried checking if i am calling this method twice, but it is being called only once

```
const source = interval(6000);
this.activityTimerSubscription = source.subscribe(val => {
  console.log(val);
  if (val > 30) {
    //this.logout();
  }
});
```

but every second the value is being repeated on the console 
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4

Comment: you mean every six seconds, right?

Comment: You probably didn't unsubscribe from the interval and now have two running simultaneously. How and when do you unsubscribe from `source`?

Comment: Most likely, this method is indeed called twice, double check this part. Add a `debugger` statement before the line with `subscribe`. Also, just to be sure: `6000 * 30` is 3 minutes, not 1 hour.

Comment: If you have this code inside `onInit()` it means that you have to free subscription inside `onDestroy()`, otherwise when `onInit()` happens again you will have 2 or more subscriptions running simultaneously. Write `console.log()` inside `onInit()`, I think you trigger it twice.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing me to right direction. I kept debugger and checked that onInit() was being called twice becuase of redirection.